# Determine if a limit converges or diverges using the definition of limit. If the sequence converges find its limit.

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^3 - 4}{8n^3 + \sqrt{n} + 5}$$

So, dividing the numerator and the denominator by $n^3$, we can tell that its limit is $3/8$. 
The question is how to prove it rigorously. 
Can anyone please help me? Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: You can certainly start by dividing the numerator and denominator by $n^3$. Once you are there, the structure of both numerator and denominator means you can do an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument (or you can use sum/difference/quotient of limit rules, as long as you have proved them). Have you tried an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument? (IN this case, it is an $\epsilon-N$ argument, since for each $\epsilon$ we have to find a large real number $N$ so that something holds).

Comment: Shouldn't your question really be about the convergence/ divergence of the function rather than the convergence/ divergence of its limit?

Answer (score 0):

$n \ge 2;$

1) $0< f(n):=\dfrac{3n^2-4}{8n^3+√n+5} < \dfrac{3n^3}{8n^3}=3/8;$

2)$g(n):=$

$\dfrac{3n^3-3n^2}{8n^3+8n^2}=(3/8)\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}<f(n);$

Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}g(n)=3/8;$

Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}g(n)\le lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n) \le 3/8$.